AMBIMA API request method not allowed
I am trying to access an AMBIMA API but, according to how to page, I need a token from authentication API. I have followed the authentication page instructions and got a response but where should have a token comes the message:

"method not allowed".

how to page: https://developers.anbima.com.br/pt/documentacao/visao-geral/como-acessar-nossas-apis/
authentication page: https://developers.anbima.com.br/pt/documentacao/visao-geral/autenticacao/#oauth2
The code I used:
 url = "https://api.anbima.com.br/oauth/access-token"
 header = {
 "Content-Type": "application/json",
 "Authorization": "Basic base64(my_id:my_access)",
 }
 
 response = requests.get(url, header)
 infos = response.json()

the result:
{'timestamp': 1714681762294, 'status': 405, 'error': 'Method Not Allowed'}

I have tried to change requests.get() to requests.post() and add the line "grant_type": "client_credentials" to the dictionary but both returns different errors. What could I do?

the documentation states that you should use post, not get. What is the error code and message when you use post?

{'result': 'failure', 'errors': [{'type': 'INVALID', 'message': 'Missing Authorization header'}], 'status': 400}

You need to call POST not GET.
Demo
Save as demo.py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

def get_access_token(client_id, client_secret):
    url = "https://api.anbima.com.br/oauth/access-token"
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    data = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    }
    
    # Using HTTPBasicAuth to handle the Basic Auth header
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret))
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()  # Returns the JSON response if successful
    else:
        return response.status_code, response.text  # Returns error status and message if not successful

# Example usage:
client_id = 'your_client_id_here'
client_secret = 'your_client_secret_here'
token_response = get_access_token(client_id, client_secret)
print(token_response)

Run it
python demo.py

Result

By Postman
URL
POST https://api.anbima.com.br/oauth/access-token

In Body
{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}



ID client/secret
From Minhas Apps tab
https://admin-developers.anbima.com.br/api-portal/user



@vini.m.oliveira, Thanks for accepting, can you give an up-vote too?
